# How to send a retrofit 2 post call with no parameters

Tags: android, post, retrofit2

I have to call an api using retrofit 2 in android. but with no values. When I does that, it shows that there must be at least 1 @field. Below is the code I am using.

```
public interface gitAPI {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/MembersWS.svc/GetMemberAvailability/MBR0011581")
    Call<Questions[]> loadQuestions();
}






Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.99:82")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    // prepare call in Retrofit 2.0
    gitAPI stackOverflowAPI = retrofit.create(gitAPI.class);

    Call<Questions[]> call = stackOverflowAPI.loadQuestions();
    call.execute();
```

Comment: try to remove @FormUrlEncoded annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare body value in your interface with next:

`@Body RequestBody body` and wrap String JSON object:

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), (new JsonObject()).toString());
```

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat sry, that was a long time ago, I don't work with Java currently. Probably link to my another question with the same answer will be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35880907/retrofit-unable-to-create-body-converter-for-class/57819497#57819497