# Retrofit: Unable to create @Body converter for class

Tags: java, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I need to send next json via retrofit 2:

```
{
    "Inspection": {
        "UUID": "name",
        "ModifiedTime": "2016-03-09T01:13",
        "CreatedTime": "2016-03-09T01:13",
        "ReviewedWith": "name2",
        "Type": 1,
        "Project": {
            "Id": 41
        },
        "ActionTypes": [1]
    }   
}
```

With Header: `Authorization: access_token_value`

I tried this:

```
//header parameter
String accessToken = Requests.getAccessToken();

JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
JsonObject inspection = new JsonObject();

inspection.addProperty("UUID","name");
inspection.addProperty("ModifiedTime","2016-03-09T01:13");
inspection.addProperty("CreatedTime","2016-03-09T01:13");
inspection.addProperty("ReviewedWith","name2");
inspection.addProperty("Type","1");

JsonObject project = new JsonObject();
project.addProperty("Id", 41);

inspection.add("Project", project);
obj.add("Inspection", inspection);

Retrofit restAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Constants.ROOT_API_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
IConstructSecureAPI service = restAdapter.create(IConstructSecureAPI.class);
Call<JsonElement> result = service.addInspection(accessToken, obj);
JsonElement element = result.execute().body();
```

But everytime i recieved exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create @Body converter for class com.google.gson.JsonObject (parameter #2)`

How can I send it ? Or any another idea how I can do it. You can even offer me with parameter as simple `String` with json inside. It will suit for me

Comment: Please post IConstructSecureAPI just to know how are you building your request.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Solution:**
declare body value in your interface with next:

`@Body RequestBody body`
and wrap String JSON object:

`RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), obj.toString());`

Comment: Solved the problem with this solution. Many thanks!

Answer (score 24):

There is chance of you kept same `@SerializedName("")` for multiple `vairable/fields/tags`

Comment: HA! This was my problem. Nice suggestion.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I wish error message was more clear on that

Answer (score 22):

You can specify a Converter when you create the Retrofit like this

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(baseurl)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build();
```

Answer (score 4):

If this is due to `@SerializedName` make sure it is not dulplicated.

For e.g. This error will be thrown in below case: (Note: `bookingId` is passed twice)

```
@SerializedName(value="bookingId", alternate={"id", "bookingId"})
```

But, this is the correct:

```
@SerializedName(value="bookingId", alternate={"id", "someOtherId", "whateverId"})
```

Answer (score 2):

*`Body`* uses a single request object, declare your request object as following

```
class Inspection {
    String UUID;
    //..... add your fields 
    Project project;      
}

class Product
{
   int Id;
   //....... add your fields 
}
```

I assume your service `IConstructSecureAPI` endpoint is:

```
@GET(...)    // change based on your api GET/POST
Call<Response> addInspection(
    @Header("Authorization") String accesstoken, 
    @Body Inspection request
);
```

and you can declare your desire `Response`.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28712275/1225337), it uses `HashMap` instead of class.

Comment: Your answer is correct but I have forgot write ".addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())" =)

Answer (score 1):

I kept getting this error when I **upgraded to Java 17**, still working fine on Java 11.

##### Here's what worked for me

- To go deeper into the Exception I put a debug point in the `Utils.java` found in retrofit stack trace.
- Doing so led me to the **narrower cause** being: `java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final byte java.time.LocalTime.hour accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.time" to unnamed module @35e2d654`
- Googling down further from here led me to https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/681#issuecomment-959646598 which in a nutshell suggests to add `--add-opens java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED` as a JVM argument.
- Boom, It worked.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `Moshi` and `Retrofit` and my problem was I forgot to add  `@JsonSerializable` annotation for the `DTO` class for `@body`.
you should add this annotation like this:

```
@JsonSerializable
data class RegisterDTO(
    @field:Json(name = "device_id") val deviceId: String,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I simply forgot to apply the *kotlinx.serialization* plugin for Gradle, so no code for the serializers was generated. Fix it via:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Interceptor to send Authorization Header in each request

```
class AuthorizationInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request originalRequest = chain.request();
        String authorizationToken = AuthenticationUtils.getToken();
        Request authorizedRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
            .header("Authorization", authorizationToken)
            .build();
        return chain.proceed(authorizedRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a pretty weird case for this issue. So I have a model that is used for parsing that has a `List` of object fields that has a wrong `SerializedName` value. It was alright before, because I'm not using it for anything. But now I wanted to use it for something, so I fixed it. Then I checked the model referenced by the `List` and saw that, somehow, I can also use it to parse in `Retrofit` even though it doesn't have a `SerializedName`, so I added one for each field of the referenced model/object. And the error started appearing after that. I checked that I do have `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())` on my `Retrofit` builder, so I'm thoroughly confused as to why I'm getting an error. Because of desperation, I removed the `SerializedName` that I've added on the referenced model, and it worked again. I think the reason my models work even without `SerializedName` is because the field name themselves already looks like the json fields, which is all lower case and snail cased. And when I added `SerializedName`, `Retrofit` considered that already an additional `SerializedName`, so I got the error which seems to be sometimes caused by multiple `SerializedName` with the same value.